# When do I divide by N in SIR and SEIR models?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

My question is kind of a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369590/differential-equations-in-sir-epidemic-model-and-obtain-ro)

I understand every separate term in the SIR model differential equations:

$ \frac{dS}{dt}=-\beta S I$

$\frac{dI}{dt} = \beta S I - \gamma I$

$\frac{dR}{dt}=\gamma I $

And I have come across and not understood these:

$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\frac{\beta}{N}{S}{I}{N}$

$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{\beta}{N}{S}I - \gamma I$

$\frac{dR}{dt}=\gamma I$

I couldn't understand the answer the the question I linked and decided that it wasn't very important. While researching, I noticed that many pages, even [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model_without_vital_dynamics) use the two interchangeably. When I tried to use the model to graph the 2014 EVD epidemic, I also ended up using the two version interchangeably, but it turned out that they require very different $\beta$ and $R_0$.

What does the N mean and what do it do?

How does the N affect $\beta$ and $R_0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the equation for $N$? In both versions you have written equation for $S$ twice.

Comment: Sorry, the second S is actually R. N is the total population (S+I+R), which is constant.

Comment: Sorry, could you point out where exactly Wiki article uses these two forms of SIR model? It's important because the second form that you have written in your post doesn't have the property that $S+I+R$ is constant over the time while the first one has this property (it's because sum of all components of vector field is zero for the first form and not everywhere zero for the second form).

Comment: Forgot I asked this, sorry for the late response.

In the SIR without vital dynamics section, the formulas are given without dividing by N, but $R_0$ is given as if they were divided by N (Otherwise it would be $βS/γ$).

In the explanation for the SEIR model the formulas are divided by N without an explanation for why this was done.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in Density dependent and Frequency dependent models. I found [this article](https://parasiteecology.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/density-dependent-vs-frequency-dependent-disease-transmission/) helpful